# How make a div link to another page?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Something isn't right! I am trying to link this div to another page but it keeps giving me 404 error when I click it. I tried replacing the page with google.com and it worked fine! I know this page works because if i run it alone in a browser it works fine! Whats going on??

```
<a style="display:block" href="../unitedStates.php">
<div id="regionsUnitedStates" class="not-open regionsButton">
<div id="regionsUnitedStatesTooltip"></div>
</div></a>
```

Comment: You are using a relative path, check if unitedStates.php exist in the parent directory and if S of States is capital as some server are case sensitive.

Comment: check your file hierarchy structure ....

Comment: check spelling and case of name of the page and also check if file is in the directory you are pointing at

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the page correctly? As it is, it appears that the page (unitedStates.php) lives on the same level as the parent folder (that's what the '..' means). If it is in the same folder, you would just write `href="unitedStates.php"`

Comment: The link is correct because I think to it directly from dreamweaver! It is right in the root of my website folder.

Comment: @figureoa.kyle710 could you possibly give us a screenshot of your folder hierarchy? (or just the url of the working in-browser page vs the url of the 404 page that you are getting.)

Comment: I figured it out! Just had to remove the dots in the beginning! I'm not sure why dreamweaver was inserting them there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You href your div to parent directory with "../". Instead this use :

```
<a style="display:block" href="/unitedStates.php">
```

Comment: Careful about linking with a `/` character. It changes the reference completely. `/unitedStates.php` refers to the page `unitedStates.php` that exists at the root level directory (if your domain were `kyle.com` it would refer to `kyle.com/unitedStates.php` no matter where you are linking from. Whereas, not using a `/` you are referencing a location that is based on what directory you are currently in.

Answer (score 0):

your path in href is doesnot exists. Try checking the absolute url of your path in browser and add it in href.